# Flat or Raised Button | Popup or New Page for Adding Account Page

Tags: design, interface

I have a button that navigates to Account Adding Page, but Im not sure it should be raised or Fiat button. Also, Account Adding Page's 70% is empty. Should I go for popup instead?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you could post an image it would be easier to give you some suggestion.

Comment: I will do as soon as possible.

Comment: @Alvaro It doesn't allow me to place more than 2 links in the post so here they are [Flat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1TW9.png) |
  [Raised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVTKe.png) |
  [Flat No Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voyHo.png) |
  [Current Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcTAD.png) |

Comment: I think you can post separate questions and get better feedback to each. Although both buttons will work, the Raised one gives it more "presence" in my opinion, no need for the icon. Also the modal looks alright to me, only thing is consider adding a title inside. Also I am not sure about the wording you are using, it gives me the impression that a user can have several accounts "added", not sure if that is the case.

Comment: I would want to create separate question too, but UX doesn't allow to open questions within a short time. And yes, user can have several accounts.

Comment: Instead of having the "You Have No Accounts Added" page, can you just take the user to the page to actually add an account?  Why make them click the button if that's the only thing they can do on the page?

Comment: @bphilipync Actually, it's a page to manage accounts, and "you have not added" and other content which shows up when you have account added are on the same page, it's not a seperate page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely suggest using a raised button. It is eye-catching and brings the attention of the visitor to the most important function on that page.

In terms of the page design, I would recommend creating a signup card with an image in the background. You could also have a frame that will show what benefits one has from creating an account.

Comment: Can you give me an example of image that I can use on page's background?

Comment: What is the topic of the webpage?

Comment: It's not webpage though, and as you can see; it's a YouTube Client.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not notice. If you want to use an image, I would suggest blurring any picture. It always looks cool.

Comment: You could also take a look at how Twitter did it here: http://www.tweetbrander.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/twitter-old-login-page-with-sunrise.jpg

Comment: Just one more thing, should I use plus icon?

Comment: Yes, a plus icon is quite common for such things. Also, if you are using a card layout, the button might look better flat.